# Is there any api or method in qt to put the device in sleep mode after a specific time if no response is coming from user?

Tags: linux, qt, sleep-mode

I am creating an application for linux and want to put the device screen in sleep mode after a particular time like 5 minutes, 10 minutes etc if no response or event occur by the user side.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there is a possibility for qt to do that, because a sleep mode is handled by the desktop environment like GNOME, Xfce, and so on. Qt itself isn't able to do this, but maybe you could use a function which just sends a command to the os, which has the opportunity to set the system to sleep. Maybe this could help you:

https://linuxer.eu/put-linux-into-sleep-from-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking on the other answer a bit here.

You could install an [eventFilter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.15/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) at a top-level in your application to monitor any input events as they occur (whether that be a mouse click or move event, keyboard event, etc.). At the same scope as that `eventFilter`, you could then use some `QTimer` with the interval set to your sleep timeout duration, which you restart every time an input occurs. That `QTimer`'s `timeout` signal could be hooked up to a slot where you put the system to sleep via a `QProcess` call out to `sh` for example.

Comment: I have used the event filter but can't able to put the device screen in sleep mode.

Comment: As the other answerer mentioned, there's not really any Qt-specific option for putting the screen to sleep. You'll need to use some system-specific command to do so, for which they supplied a helpful link. Combining our answers, you could simply do something like `QProcess::execute("sh", QStringList() << "echo mem > /sys/power/state");`